# The average age of a highly skilled factory worker in the U.S. is 56 (or so)

Tags: united-states, education, employment

In a [2012 NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2012/11/25/magazine/skills-dont-pay-the-bills.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0&mtrref=www.michiganfuture.org) piece we read that

> The average age of a highly skilled factory worker in the U.S. is now 56. “That’s average,” says Hal Sirkin, the lead author of the study. “That means there’s a lot who are in their 60s. They’re going to retire soon.” And there are not enough trainees in the pipeline, he said, to replace them.

Is this analysis robust or is highly dependant on how one defines "highly skilled"? Has it been subject to peer commentary, etc.?

Comment: The report in question appears to be [this](https://www.bcg.com/publications/2013/lean-manufacturing-us-skills-gap-could-threaten-manufacturing-renaissance.aspx): "The U.S. Skills Gap: Could It Threaten a Manufacturing Renaissance?"  Harold L. Sirkin, Michael Zinser, and Justin Rose.  However, it's dated some 9 months after the NYT article, and it doesn't contain the exact "rock-bottom" quote from the article, nor anything about worker age.  But it's the only thing by Sirkin that seems close.  It does not appear to have been published in a peer-reviewed journal.